# The prefix "pex" for attribute "pex:outputField" associated with element type "a" is not bound

Tags: oauth, salesforce, apex

Why I am getting this error?

> The prefix "pex" for attribute "pex:outputField" associated with
>   element type "a" is not bound

[image]

Comment: it's probably a phantom error. The language server sometimes gives you wrong errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output fields are put together wrong. You need a value attribute to set the output fields to your opportunitiy fields. Instead of `<apex:outputField="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>`
It should be...
`<apex:outputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>`
Furthermore, you seem to have a space between 'Close' and 'Date' and again with 'Account' and 'Name' which will throw further errors.

Comment: oh yes, exactly!! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! @ShivangKumar